# Append data for multiple records in a single field record using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose i have a table as follows

```
--------------------------
Name  |  Subject  |  Marks
--------------------------
Jon   |  Maths    |  80
--------------------------
Rob   |  Biology  |  90
--------------------------
```

And I want to get output as

```
Jon,Maths,80,Rob,Biology,90
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What if there are 1000 rows? In that case do you want 3000 columns?

Comment: so `15` columns? And how do you decide `top 5`? based on `name` or `marks`?

Comment: Based on Marks,so 15 columns are to be given as o/p comma separated in a single filed record as REPORT_OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this.

```
SELECT listagg(csv,',') within
GROUP (
     ORDER BY constant_no) derived_string
FROM
(SELECT 1 AS constant_no,
        name||','||subject||','||to_char(Marks) AS csv
 FROM tbl
 WHERE rownum<6)
GROUP BY constant_no
```

Here first I am concatenating the 3 columns and assigning a constant for each row after selecting only 5 rows from the table. Then I am using this derived table to `listagg` again to get the desired output.

So this query will generate a table like below

```
SELECT 1 AS constant_no,
            name||','||subject||','||to_char(Marks) AS csv
     FROM tbl
     WHERE rownum<6
```

Derived table output

```
+-------------+-------------------+
| CONSTANT_NO |       CSV         |
+-------------+-------------------+
|           1 | Jon,Maths,80      |
|           1 | Rob,Biology,90    |
|           1 | Utsav,Maths,60    |
|           1 | Suresh,Biology,95 |
|           1 | Tim,Maths,40      |
+-------------+-------------------+
```

Now you can use this in `listagg` function.

Here is the complete query if you want to test

```
with tbl(Name, Subject, Marks) as (
select 'Jon', 'Maths', 80 from dual union all
select 'Rob', 'Biology', 90 from dual union all
select 'Utsav', 'Maths', 60 from dual union all
select 'Suresh', 'Biology', 95 from dual union all
select 'Tim', 'Maths', 40 from dual union all
select 'Ramesh', 'Maths', 80 from dual
)
SELECT listagg(csv,',') within
GROUP (
     ORDER BY constant_no) derived_string
FROM
(SELECT 1 AS constant_no,
        name||','||subject||','||to_char(Marks) AS csv
 FROM tbl
 WHERE rownum<6)
GROUP BY constant_no
```

Output

```
Jon,Maths,80,Rob,Biology,90,Suresh,Biology,95,Tim,Maths,40,Utsav,Maths,60
```

Note: The output is for random 5 rows. Unless you have keys to determine order, oracle will not necessarily return rows in any particular order.

Comment: Thanks you so much Utsav getting the result as expected

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
SELECT listagg (jColumn , ',')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY jColumn) enames
FROM (SELECT TOP 5 name + ',' + subject + ',' + Marks as jColumn 
      FROM emp) a
GROUP BY jColumn
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen now get first top 5 and then concat records

Comment: This will not work as you need some common key to `group by` in `listagg`. You can hardcode any number in derived table and use `group by` on that.